# How to find the expected value of $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{|x|}{\sigma}\right)$

Tags: probability, integration, expectation, moment-problem

> How to find the expected value of x with pdf $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{|x|}{\sigma}\right)$, where x takes all real numbers.

The original question asks to find the Method of Moment estimator of $\sigma$, so I was thinking to find the expected value of $x$ first, and rearrange it to get the estimator of $\sigma$.

I tried to integrate $\int xf(x) \, dx$ from $-\infty$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $\infty$, and I got $\sigma$ for $0$ to $\infty$, but I couldn't solve $-\infty$ to $0$.

Comment: Density is symmetric (Laplace distribution), so the expected value is $0$.

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions in  future questions. And please show how you attempted to solve the problem or  give extra information about question.

Comment: You really need to show some significant work. How to start should not be a mystery.

Comment: I can't help suspecting that you mean you want the expected value of a random variable whose density is $f(x) = \frac 1 {2 \sigma} \exp (-\frac {|x|} \sigma)$, rather than "the expected value of $f(x) = \frac 1 {2 \sigma} \exp (-\frac {|x|} \sigma)$". $\qquad$

Comment: Sorry guys I edited it again.

Comment: Your last paragraph makes me wonder if your difficulty is that you missed the fact that if $x<0$ then $|x|=-x$. $\qquad$

Comment: If the expected value is 0, does it mean the method of moment estimator of $\sigma$ is also 0?

Comment: No. But $E(|X|)=\sigma$ so you can use that to estimate $\sigma$.